# For discord.py, how would I turn the author's id into the discord user's actual name?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm having trouble with message.author.id. When I ask a bot to return the user's ID, it returns the well... user ID. But that's not what I want. I want it to say the user's discord name (for an example, instead of like 13284701972315 it would say MyName #0000). I'm making a bot which will give out brownie points on command. Here's and example of what it might say.

> 311661286213550091 has given 22 brownie points to @AceFTW. They currently have 22
>   brownie points!

I'd like it to say something like this:

> @tristan360 has given 22 brownie points to @AceFTW. They currently have 22
>   brownie points!

I'm looking for a way for the bot to display the user's name instead of the user's ID.

Comment: um... I did everything u asked me to do... wat...

Comment: It would certainly help to have the source code that you are working with.
At the moment I am having a similar issue, but I am not able to get the (at)mentions working.<br />
if you do something like `await ctx.send(ctx.message.author)` that should give you the ID (MyName #0000)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a `Member` object already, you can access the name straight away.

```
# member is <Member id=... name=MyName#0000>
member.name  # MyName
member.nick  # MyNick
member.display_name  # MyNick if nick is not None, else MyName
member.mention  # @MyName
str(member)  # MyName#0000
```

If you do not have a `Member` object, but do have a `Guild` (`Server` in discord.py 0.x,) you can use the [`Guild.get_member`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member) method.

```
member = guild.get_member(userID)
member.name  # MyName
```

If you don't have any information at all starting, you can use the [`Client.get_user_info`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Client.get_user_info) method. Note, this returns a `User` not a `Member`, so you will not have access to nicknames, roles, etc.

```
user = bot.get_user_info(userID)
user.name  # MyName
user.nick  # Error
```

Comment: There's also [`User.mention`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.mention), which looks like what they're looking for.

Comment: Good note. Will edit in thanks.