# Discord.py - How to (at)mention a Discord user from Bot Command

Tags: python, discord.py

**Not really a dupe? Explaination:**
[This question is not looking to (at)mention a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51978974/how-to-mention-a-sender-of-a-command-discord-py)
[This question lists member.mention but does not provide a complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50262096/for-discord-py-how-would-i-turn-the-authors-id-into-the-discord-users-actual)

**My Question**
Using Discord.py (if the title was not clear enough) I am trying to figure out how to add the **@mention** attribute to a Discord user when they run a command.

**Example:**
User input: $99
Bot output: **@User** your quote is: Bingpot!

**UPDATE: 10/24/2019** 
- @epic-programmer pointed out a pretty egregious copy-paste error which I have fixed :)
- That fix sets "member" as an argument for the command.  What I would like to to is get the members display name, and use that in the command output (as an @mention)

## Google Answer

```
@commands.command()
async def mention_ping(self, ctx, member : discord.Member):
    await ctx.send(f"PONG {member}")
```

## My Code (Updated: Use @epic-programmers partial fix)

```
import random
import discord

from discord.ext import commands

#----
tokenfile = 'token.txt'
with open(tokenfile) as tf:
    line = tf.readline()
    TOKEN = line.rstrip()
#----

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@bot.command(name='99', help='Responds with a random quote from Brooklyn 99')
async def nine_nine(ctx, member : discord.Member):
    brooklyn_99_quotes = [
        'I\'m the human form of the  emoji.',
        'Bingpot!',
        (
            'Cool. Cool cool cool cool cool cool cool, '
            'no doubt no doubt no doubt no doubt.'
        ),
    ]

    response = random.choice(brooklyn_99_quotes)
    await ctx.send("{} your quote is: {}".format(member, response))

bot.run( TOKEN)
```

## Resources I've looked at

- https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/107413/discord.Member
- https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message
- https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_bot.py#L46-L49

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `member` argument is on the wrong location. Try moving it to the `def` statement.

```
@bot.command(name='99', help='Responds with a random quote from Brooklyn 99')
async def nine_nine(ctx, member : discord.Member):
    brooklyn_99_quotes = [
        'I\'m the human form of the  emoji.',
        'Bingpot!',
        (
            'Cool. Cool cool cool cool cool cool cool, '
            'no doubt no doubt no doubt no doubt.'
        ),
    ]

    response = random.choice(brooklyn_99_quotes)
    await ctx.send("{} your quote is: {}".format(member, response))

bot.run( TOKEN)
```

EDIT: In order to mention the current user calling the command, you can do:

```
from typing import Optional

@bot.command(name='99', help='Responds with a random quote from Brooklyn 99')
async def nine_nine(ctx, member : Optional[discord.Member] = None):
    member = member or ctx.author
    brooklyn_99_quotes = [
        'I\'m the human form of the  emoji.',
        'Bingpot!',
        (
            'Cool. Cool cool cool cool cool cool cool, '
            'no doubt no doubt no doubt no doubt.'
        ),
    ]

    response = random.choice(brooklyn_99_quotes)
    await ctx.send("{} your quote is: {}".format(member, response))

bot.run( TOKEN)
```

This code block will check for a ping, and if it does not find one, then it will default to the user calling the command.

Comment: Wow.... I really really foolish for not catching -that- :D Sometimes a second pair of eyes really helps ;) That seems to work, except that I need to pass "member" as an argument. The ultimate goal is to mention the user that initiates the command. Example: input: $99 output: "@BanjoFox, your quote is: [quote from list]" i've had some luck with adding author = ctx.message.author to the function, but that does not @mention the user :(